# How to communicate with ubuntu/linux terminal using java without Runtime.getRuntime().exec("trminal cmds")?

Tags: java, linux

While trying to start and restart a service in ubuntu14.04 .Service expected to start without using Runtime.getRuntime.exec("some linux command");
how to start service without using Runtime.getRuntime.exec();
Any help would be appreciated.Also welcome alternative ideas .

Comment: I think If you run any command from JVM you will need runtime for that the same procedure we all know about because JVM and command line are separate platflorm. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Sarz you are right . without JVM runtime java does not work. I dont want execute my terminal command on java . Is there any way to do this.But i need to get same response.

Comment: When you are running Java application basically you are in JVM. What ever you do is through JVM. So, If you want to run directly on terminal run **bash/sh** file through JVM